# Issue regarding setup the cronjob for issue reminder

Tags: redmine

I have wrote a script for issue reminder

```
cd /var/www/redmine
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/wrappers/rake reminder:exec RAILS_ENV="production
```

But while running the above script getting error

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/htmlentities-4.3.1/lib/htmlentities/mappings/expanded.rb:465: warning: duplicated key at line 466 ignored: "inodot"
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'reminder:exec' (see --tasks)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 0):

The rake task seems to be added by the [redmine_mail_reminder](https://github.com/jcppkkk/redmine_mail_reminder) plugin. Since the task can not be found apparently, you probably don't have this plugin installed properly (or at all).

It is also possible that you are not in the correct directory. For the rake task to work, you have to change to the root directory of Redmine, i.e. the directory containing the `app`, `lib` and `plugins` directories as well as the `Gemfile`.

Finally, Redmine itself can send reminders without the use of plugins with the use of a different rake task which is shipped with Redmine itself:

```
bundle exec rake redmine:send_reminders days=7 RAILS_ENV="production"
```

See [RedmineReminderEmails](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineReminderEmails) for details.